# Which part of the Magic Flute is this music from?

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music

There exist this music that comprises of variations on a Theme by Mozart. As I understand it comes from the Magic Flute. I would love to know which part.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iaEcDgxm8es

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's from a number at the end of Act I, ["Das klinget so herrlich."](https://youtu.be/9fpionW0Aoc?t=22s)